# How to Print the selected rows from the Datagridview in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

If i select the checkbox that particular data only Printed to the Paper

[image]

I have tried a lot of code but the entire DataGridView was printed. I just want to print the selected rows only

I expect the output like this

[image]

Comment: Please share some code so we can better assist you

Comment: For example, with selected cell you get row index, then for each cell in row x do y.

Comment: If it didn't work then you did it wrong. If you don't show us what you did, there's no way that we can possibly know what's wrong with it.  If you mean that you just copied code off the web and it didn;t do what you wanted then that's not actually making an effort on your part.  You need to make an effort to understand what such code is doing and thus what changes are required and then try to make those changes.  If what you think should work doesn't work when you try it, THEN would be the time to post a question here and include ALL the relevant information.

Comment: Learn the language before asking beginner questions i'm sure you will find this answer on google, not hard to loop the rows and check 4th column if selected then print that row is it?

Comment: @Devcon Exactly, Thanks for your reply

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you, I got a new way to get the output, i posted it below

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you so much Guys!!!**
Finally i find a new way to print my datagridview

**1)** *First i save the DataGridview like this below*

Private Sub btn_save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_save.Click
        Try

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvData.Rows.Count - 1
            If CBool(dgvData.Rows(i).Cells("Column4").Value) Then
                str = " insert into tbl_dummy(opd,name,testname,category,cost) values (" & TextBox1.Text & ",'" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & dgvData.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & "','" + dgvData.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value & "','" + dgvData.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value & "') "
                cmd = New SqlCommand(str, cn)
                openconnection()
                da.InsertCommand = cmd
                da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
        Next
        MessageBox.Show("Data Added Successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        closeconnection()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

**2)** Then i take print from the database , By this way it gives the exact result what i need.